# Firebase database: unique username

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been looking at the following post
[Firebase android : make username unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique)

I have done more or less the same as the answer. But i am missing something. Maybe someone here have better eyes than me and can point out why it is not working

**My code**

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

  Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
  Map<String, Object> userValues = new HashMap<>();
  Map<String, Object> usernameValues = new HashMap<>();
  userValues.put("email", email);
  userValues.put("username", username);
  usernameValues.put(username, user.getUid());
  childUpdates.put("/Users/" + user.getUid() + "/", userValues);
  childUpdates.put("/Usernames/", usernameValues);


  mDatabaseReference.updateChildren(childUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
      hideProgressDialog();
      if(!task.isSuccessful()) {
        //Username taken. Force user in next view to pick one
      }
      Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  });
```

**Snippet from the rules**

```
"Users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid === $uid",
    ".read": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password'",
    "Username": {
      ".validate": "
        !root.child('Usernames').child(newData.val()).exists() ||
        root.child('Usernames').child(newData.val()).val() == auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

In my head, I should add rules for `Usernames` as well. But i got really confused by the link above and the answer given. What should i then logically add to the Usernames ruleset

i am guessing that i need to do something like

```
"Usernames" : {
   "$uid": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth != null",
                ".validate" : "!root.child('Usernames').child($uid).exists()"
   }
}
```

Any help is thankful. Let me know if you want me to explain anything further

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I think i have fixed most of it. Will post an answer when i am certain. Right now it looks like i was sending in username as lower case. Then my rules where expecting upper case.  Now i am just trying to figure out how to write to 'Usernames' only when it is the same user or if username does not exist

Comment: Did you fix it? Can you post an answer?