# Firebase Database unique value?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to make userName unique in this database structure of Firebase android ,if yes then please help me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: you could make username key instead those generated keys.

Comment: This was already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique

Comment: No i need this key and i need two unique key mobile number and email address.

Comment: I already visited those links @dePhantom but it won't help me.:(

Comment: The linked question contains links to other questions also covering the topic. At the very least those answer should allow you to get started on ensuring the uniqueness of those values. If you get stuck somewhere, post a question with the [minimal code (JSON+security rules+Android code, all as text, no screenshots please) of where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).