# Firebase permission denied when checking unique username

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to check if the username already is in use. This function gets called when the current user does not have a child of "username":

```
func createUsername()
{
    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().updateChildValues([
        "users/\(userID!)/username": username.text!,
        "usernames/\(username.text!)": userID!
        ], withCompletionBlock: { (error, reference) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("disallowed")
                // Write was disallowed because username exists
            }
    })
}
```

In combination with this  rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        "username": {
      ".read": true,
          ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()",
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        }
      }
    },
    "usernames": {
      "$username": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()",
        ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val() == root.child('users/' + auth.uid + '/username').val()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got the answer from: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/dA1Lkykd-tk
I get this error message:

> [Firebase/Database][I-RDB03812] updateChildValues: at / failed: permission_denied

I am not sure why this wont work. I also tried this answer: [Firebase android : make username unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique) But this did not work for me. There is something wrong with the rules but I dont know what.

Update, little change in rules, still same error:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        "username": {
      ".read": true,
          ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()",
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        }
      }
    },
    "usernames": {
      "$username": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()",
        ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val() == newData.parent().parent().child('users/' + auth.uid + '/username').val()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also changed the parent() things, but it wouldn't work aswell. I changed to 4 parents, and 0 parents. Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** The problem comes from this validation rule:

```
".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val() == root.child('users/' + auth.uid + '/username').val()"
```

You're comparing the new data against the *current* root. Since the user has just been created `/users/$uid` won't yet exist.

What you want to do is compare the new data against the *new* users node. To get to this node, you should navigate from `newData` up to the *new* root when comparing:

```
".validate": "newData.isString() && 
  newData.val() == newData.parent().parent().child('users/' + auth.uid + '/username').val()"
```

---

*I'll leave my previous response below, since it may prove useful in learning how to troubleshoot a problem like this.*

I just pasted your rules into a project of mine, simplified them a bit and used your code without problems. I'm not sure why you're having a problem.

The code:

```
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInAnonymously(completion: { (user, error) in
        let username = "puf"
        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        self.ref.child("42188459").updateChildValues([
            "users/\(userID!)/username": username,
            "usernames/\(username)": userID!
        ], withCompletionBlock: { (error, reference) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("disallowed")
                // Write was disallowed because username exists
            }
        })
    })
```

The rules snippet:

```
  "users": {
    "$uid": {
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
      "username": {
        ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()",
      }
    }
  },
  "usernames": {
    "$username": {
      ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()",
    }
  }
```

The resulting JSON:

```
{
  "usernames" : {
    "puf" : "DBP4Pw3uiwQfUaDJw1XBR8oFBUK2"
  },
  "users" : {
    "DBP4Pw3uiwQfUaDJw1XBR8oFBUK2" : {
      "username" : "puf"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I copied your update rule and replaced it with the old values. However, I still get the an error. This error occurs at the line .validate, the rule I just copied. In the simulator in Firebase, I also get the error. I had these settings: Write, location: /usernames/dfggdfg/, json values: {
  "key": "value"
}, verified: YES, then execute. Reading works, but writing still has some issues. The rest of the rules are exactly the same as stated above. I will update the current rules I am using. XCode still gives the same error.