# Firebase setDisplayName prevent duplicates

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Using the examples in firebase own docs its simple to update the `displayname` of a user

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName("Jane Q. User")
        .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"))
        .build();
```

However, I would like to know how to enforce unique displaynames. I have seen other solutions that seem to re-implement the user as a node in the database [Firebase android : make username unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique) but this seems like a lot of extra work, surely there is a way to enforce the uniqueness of data within the Firebase user object created at authentication.

Comment: There is currently no way to make a value unique beyond what's covered in the post you linked and many more. I agree it would ideally be less work, but it currently isn't.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen