# How to check if specific data exists in Firebase Database before inserting new data?

Tags: android, database, firebase

This question does not really need code snippets or anything, I guess.

I've just implemented Firebase in my app, nothing else, enabling Google and Email Sign-In's.
Now, every time a user logs in, I want to add his/her "name" and "email" to the "users" child in my database. But before that, I want to check if that user has already signed in before (perhaps by checking if the same email address already exists), and if not, then I want to insert that data in the database.

Please help.

PS: If the question is unclear, or badly formed, please suggest how I can improve it. Thanks!

Comment: This topic has been covered quite a bit already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique (and the links from my comment there). If you're having trouble implementing it, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay, I will look into it, and will will share the code, too, if I can't do it. Thanks :)