# Firebase check if user's displayname/username is unique

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to ensure that before attempting to sign up a `displayName` is unique. I have a user table like this:

```
$uid: {
  ..data..
  displayName: 'noob839',
}
```

I have done an `".indexOn": ["displayName"]` to optimise this, now I need to (from the client) check every user to see if `displayName` value is already taken.

It is very important that the current user can only read that field of another user.

Is this a recommended approach? How would I go about iterating over every user to see if the display name is unique? Thanks in advance.

*P.S. Since we cannot attach data to users we must make a seperate user object which complicates app design since it adds another point of failure for sign ups, and data retrieval (a two step process). That's a shame!*

Comment: The recommended approach is to keep the values that you want to be unique in a collection as the key. So create a collection of `displayNames` and then use the (potentially encoded) display name as the key in there. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique

Answer (score 1):

Query on that name so you are not looping through the users:

*This is in `Angular2` but can converted to the appropriate language* (what I had already)

```
/*
    Available username
*/
public availUsername(displayName: string): Observable<any[]> {
    this.users = this.AF.database.list("users", {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'displayName',
            equalTo: displayName
        }
    }).first();
    return this.users;
}

this.availUsername("theblindprophet").
   subscribe(response => {
       if(response.length == 0) {
           // No one has this displayName
       } else {
           // someone has it
       }
   });
```

If there are no results (array length of 0) then no one has that name.

Assumed you have users stored under `users`.