# How to setup rules in firebase to prevent same nicknames?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

```
"RegisterRequests": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid && !root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).exists()",
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['Nickname']) && newData.hasChildren(['Whatever'])",
    "Nickname": {
      ".validate": "newData.val().length > 1 && newData.val().length < 17 && !root.child('Users').child('Nickname').child(newData.val()).exists() && !root.child('RegisterRequests').child('Nickname').child(newData.val()).exists()"
    },
    "Whatever": {
    ".validate": "newData.val() > 0 && newData.val() < 6"
    },
    "$other": { ".validate": false }
  }
}

"Users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    "Nickname": {

    }
  }
}
```

These are my rules for my database. I am trying to prevent adding data that contains a nickname already existing in `Users` or `RegisterRequests`. I think I fail here: `!root.child('Users').child('Nickname').child(newData.val()).exists() && !root.child('RegisterRequests').child('Nickname').child(newData.val()).exists()`
 because `Nickname` has value not children. But I don't know how to make this check. Also I don't know if this is a correct way to check for children anyway, because I am missing the Identifier child in this hierarchy. Can anyone help me?

Comment: To enforce unique nicknames, you should create a top-level collection `/nicknames` where the keys are the nicknames, and the value of each key is the UID of the "owner" of that nickname. Since keys are guaranteed to be unique, storing the nicknames as keys ensures that the nicknames are also unique.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique, the other answers linked from there, and many others.