# Firebase unique field value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

So I found this answer on how to create a unique field in Firebase: [Firebase android : make username unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique)

But my question is, if I have multiple unique fields (in different collections) does that mean I have to create multiple `usernames` collections that will hold all my unique fields.

Here is an example. Say I have two collections `users` and `groups`. In my users, I have an `email` field that must be unique. In my `groups` I have an `address` field that must be unique. So does that mean (according to the above answer) I need to have these collections in my root:

- users
- uniqueUserEmails
- groups
- uniqueGroupAddresses

This seems horrible? Is this a big downside to nosql vs sql? In sql it would be so easy to say `UNIQUE` in the field(column) creation

Answer (score 1):

If you need some value (or combination of values) to be unique, you need to create a node that contains that value (or combination) as its key. If you need to guarantee that multiple values (or combinations) are unique, you'll need multiple of such nodes.

When you have a database that *does* support uniqueness constructs, it is pretty much doing the same behind the scenes. The only difference is that the database then does it automatically, where here you have to do it yourself.

Comment: My users was this `[GUID123: {name: 'Frank', email: 'x@g.com'}, GUID456: {name 'John', email: 'x2@g.com'}]` should I then rather create this: `[x@g.com: {name: 'Frank'}, x2@g.com: {name 'John'}]`?

Comment: Ignore the `[]` sorry, should be `{}`

Comment: `you need to create a node` What do you mean with this? Do you mean the same as `you need to create a collection`?

Comment: The question you linked to is about the Firebase Realtime Database, where the data model is based on nodes and value. In Firestore that would indeed be a collection.