# Firebase realtime database rules check if node with a certain key exists across all nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a node "purchasetokens" - "$userId" - ""$purchaseToken"" and a key "valid:True/False" that is set by my cloud function only. How can I set a rule to make sure that the "$purchaseToken" doesn't exists across all "$userId" with a "valid:True" key?

```
"purchasetokens": {
   ".read": false,
   "$userId": {
        "$purchaseToken": {
          ".write": "auth !== null && <<!data.exists() with "valid:True" key across all $userId nodes>>",                      
          "valid": {   # this key can only be modified from the cloud function
              ".write": false,
            },
```

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but the `".write": false` under `valid` doesn't do anything. If the user is granted write permission on the `$purchaseToken` node, you can't take that permission away at a lower level. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#read_and_write_rules_cascade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to search across nodes in security rules. The only thing you can do is read from a known path or check if a known path exists.

That's why you'll have to reframe your use-case to fit those product limitations. Since you want to check if a certain valid token exists, you should either store an (additional) list of valid tokens or a list of tokens with their validity.

An example of the former is this global list of all valid tokens:

```
validTokens: {
  "purchaseToken1": true,
  "purchaseToken2": true
}
```

The `true` value in the above is just a dummy value and has no meaning, but you could decide to make it meaningful and for example use `true` for valid tokens and `false` for invalid ones.

With the above data structure in place you can then check in your rules with:

```
".write": "root.child('validTokens').child($purchaseToken).exists()"
```

If you decide to use `true`/`false` values to indicate validity, the check would become:

```
".write": "root.child('validTokens').child($purchaseToken).val() === true"
```

Comment: This is a very interesting solution! Thanks a lot!

Comment: But in theory, it would be possible to submit the same token from different users simultaneously and they would all be validated because there is some delay until a token is validated from the google api and the validated token written into the validTokens node in firebase database, correct?

Comment: That depends on your use-case. If multiple users can submit the same token in practice and that shouldn't be allowed, you'll want to especially use the data structure I mention, along with a [transaction]() and [security rules]() to ensure uniqueness. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/56723701, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41446816 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/25294478 (wow, that one is 9½ years old by now )

Comment: thank you for the links. An no it's not directly possible, I'm just worrying about theoretically possible abuse-cases.

Answer (score 1):

try the following may be this is what you want correctly ...

```
{
  "rules": {
    "purchasetokens": {
      "$userId": {
        "$purchaseToken": {
          ".write": "!root.child('purchasetokens').child($userId).child($purchaseToken).child('valid').val() === true"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it will checks if the valid key of the specified $purchaseToken under the corresponding $userId is true. If it is true, the write operation will be denied, preventing duplicate purchase tokens with a valid: true key.

EDIT OTHER POSSIBLE SOLUTION

```
{
  "rules": {
    "purchasetokens": {
      "$userId": {
        "$purchaseToken": {
          ".write": "!data.exists() || !data.child('valid').val()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but as i can see in your case the best will be the following

```
{
  "rules": {
    "purchasetokens": {
      ".read": false,
      "$userId": {
        "$purchaseToken": {
          ".write": "auth !== null && !root.child('purchasetokens').child($userId).child($purchaseToken).child('valid').exists()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the above code will use the auth !== null condition to ensure that the user is authenticated. Additionally, we use the !root.child('purchasetokens').child($userId).child($purchaseToken).child('valid').exists() condition to check if the $purchaseToken exists across all $userId nodes and if it was never valid before. This condition ensures that the token is unique and has not been marked as valid previously.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but as far as I understand, this isn't what I need. I want to check all purchasetokens across all user nodes, not just the user who tries to write. Because maybe the user tries to validate a purchase token from another user which would work because purchase tokens aren't bound to users. It would be returned valid from googleapi because it's a valid token. So I have to check if the $purchasetoken exists across all users and was never valid before.