# Do we get billed for reading a non-existent document in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, billing

Let's say I wanna check if there is a localized document in EN in my Firestore. I will try to read:

```dart
DocumentSnapshot englishDocument = _firestore.document('/books/000000/lang/en').get();
```

Then I check if the document exists. If it doesn't check whether the book exists in Spanish.

```dart
if (!englishDocument.exists) {
      DocumentSnapshot spanishDocument = _firestore.document('/books/000000/lang/es').get();
    }
```

## Now 3 scenarios:

**- The book is available in EN:** I get billed for 1 read

**- The book is NOT available in EN but it is in ES:** Do I get billed for 1 or 2 reads?

**- The book is NOT available in neither of the two languages:** Do I get billed for 2 reads or does it count as 0 reads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `get()` to read a document costs 1 read operation in all situations.  There is no way to check to see if a document exists without paying the cost of that read.  You are essentially paying for the privilege of using a massively scalable index to quickly tell you about the document.

Please see the documentation about [minimum charges for queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#minimum-charge):

> There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results.

See also: [How to check if a document exists with a given id in firestore, without costing money?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919858/how-to-check-if-a-document-exists-with-a-given-id-in-firestore-without-costing)